# Tips on writing a character with bipolar disorder

Tags: creative-writing, fiction, research

I am writing a novel about a young man who is grieving the loss of his mother. He's also been diagnosed with bipolar 2 disorder in the last two years.

I really want to do his character justice, and I want to properly convey what living with a mental illness might be like so I'm reading memoirs about people who have the illness. I'm reading articles on bipolar 2 disorder and researching what not to do when writing a character with a mental illness.

I'm still not confident that I'll be able to write this character.

I guess my question is, how would you guys go about doing research to write a character with a mental illness? How long do you think one should research before tackling the story?

Comment: Is this protagonist supposed to be the kind who looks good (because they are an unreliable narrator), or are the flaws and problems very obvious or antagonized?

Comment: Is this "mother dropped dead of stroke out of the blue" or "mother struggled with an illness for a long time and finally died"?  That will be a big influence.  If he's known her prognosis for a long time, he's already started grieving.

Comment: @Mary I had planned for the mother to have passed from a heart attack.

Comment: @Crafter I'd like for his flaws and problems to be very obvious.

Comment: *writing* questions come to my mind that outweigh pure research: what is the narrative purpose of giving your MC this handicap (flaws are something the MC needs to change, handicaps can't be changed), What is the purpose of diagnosing prior to the story. How will the handicap be relatable to the reader, and what is his arc (if any) in accepting it? If you left it unnamed (undiagnosed) does the character still work? Is being specific about the diagnosis intended to inform the reader or the MC? How much does his handicap impact events and plot? Who is the narrator, and what is the story's theme?

Comment: if you can answer the writing 'why' questions above, it should help you better decide when 'enough is enough' to accomplish the effect or goal.

Comment: @wetcircuit A handicap is not a flaw, but living with one does provide challenges to overcome.  Anyone who has been to physical therapy for a physical handicap, learning to overcome the disadvantage is part of the journey.    And not all flaws are overcome... sometimes accepting your flaws is enough to overcome them.   Consider "Wreck It Ralph" where his story is about accepting his status as a video game villain and the fact that the game won't work if he doesn't do his job.

Comment: @hszmv, that comment took a bizarre left turn.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, why not research on a way the reader will relate with the character despite the disorder. Though I believe as a reader that stories work best when it spuns around a person and relationships rather than the illness.
Secondly, it is important to know upfront what relationship your character has with his or her illness, how that affects the interplay of external and internal worlds and the access others have to the character’s problems. It can be as complicated as you wish,but don’t leave the readers behind.
Thirdly, as a writer, you should try to pinpoint the disorder, even if your character is never properly diagnosed because Disorders are defined by specific behaviors and cognitive flaws, so the more you narrow down the diagnosis, the more you know about how your character might behave, feel and think